# Get all pins from Pinterest.com

Tags: pinterest, pins

We are working on a website (php) , in which the loginned user view their pins and add to the site.

For getting the user pins we are using rss feed (pinterest.com//feed.rss), but it is retrieving only 25 pins and we need all the pin from pinterest for that user.

So please suggest us that how to do this ?

Thanks

Rgds
Sanjay Shekhawat